# Was Bhishma really not aware about the difference between Dharma and tradition?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, dharma, karna, bhishma

In Star Plus [Mahabharat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabharat_(2013_TV_series)), season 3 episode 2, when Karna was a teenager, he wins a little competition which involved bow and arrow. Karna won, but Bhishma only praised his chariot driver skills, and told Karna's father, "here, in our area, it is tradition that only *Kshatriya* can be archer. And tradition is Dharma".

Very soon, Krishna says (there's a 1-2 minute *class* by Krishna in every episode, who briefly talks about the main thing of the episode, in an indirect way, to educate people and relate it to current life): There was tradition that people worshiped *Indra*, but later they found Dharma inside that tradition by breaking that tradition and worshiping *Gowardhana*.

So clearly, *Krishna* wants to prove what Bhishma said is not always true.

Also, I'm not sure what Krishna said was a message by Mahabharat producers/directors/content team, or was it really written in original Mahabharata.

So, was Bhishma really unaware of it?

Comment: Tradition is dharma..there is no contradiction in it..as per Manu Smriti 2.12, the Practice of cultured Men i.e. tradition is Dharma..but i don't think Karna appeared in front of Bhishma earlier than Kaurva-Pandvas test day.. there also i think it was Kripacharya who said such things..bdw Bhisma was very much knowledgeable in different means of Dharma..there is dedicated Parva (complete book) in Mahabaharata for his teachings on such topics..

Comment: I remember the episode, Yes, but I don't remember such a thing happening in the actual Mahabharat book.

Comment: The incident depicted in the TV Serial is complete fiction.

Comment: question should be directed to writers of tv series, not a question about Hindu religion.

Comment: @Surya but then it looks bad to me. I watch it to learn messages. But then I can't decide when did someone actually said a right thing, and when wrong.

Comment: @Vikas The problem is the writers of the serial have projected their own ideas and philosophies onto the characters of the story, so it's not always justifiable by our scriptures.

Comment: The thing I would suggest is accept all the general advice whichever appeals to you, but don't *entirely* believe in anything the serial calls "Dharma".

Comment: Was worshiping Gowardhana hill by Krishname mentioned in Mahabharata? @Vikas Kumar